# Contar filas en con un subquery SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente *query*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     NoEconomico
    ,count(NoEconomico) AS Totales
FROM prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria
WHERE RPMEventos <> 0
    AND AccountId = 9159
    AND FechaInicio BETWEEN '2016-11-27'
        AND '2016-12-31'
    AND CeEmplazamiento LIKE 'Celaya'
GROUP BY NoEconomico
```

Que me arroja los siguientes datos:

```
**NoEconomico              Totales**
CL0201/CEL10017          2
RCL018/CEL17698          5
RCL023/CEL10940          3
RCL026/CEL10931          2
RCL031/CEL10934          2
RCL033/CEL8243           4
RCL036/CEL17705          5
RCL042/CEL10945          3
RCL047-RCL048/CEL6957    5
RCL049-RCL050/CEL11449   5
RCL056/CEL8139           2
RCL102/CEL17695          1
RCL103/CEL10941          5
RCL105/CEL10939          1
RCL109/CEL10946          3
RCL113/CEL17703          2
RCL115/CEL17701          5
RCL122/CEL9986           1
RCL123/CEL6955           2
RCL135/CEL10932          3
RCL140/CEL17704          2
RCL141/CEL10938          2
RCL144/CEL17699          5
RCL145/CEL17700          5
RCL146/CEL11462          5
RCL154/CEL10935          3
RCL155/CEL17696          4
RCLD01/CEL10949          1
RCLTC2/CEL17702          5
RESERVA/CEL16138         2
RESERVA/CEL16177         1
RESERVA/CEL9897          3
RESERVA/CEL9927          2
RTL264/CEL18253          1
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que me cuente el total de las filas (registros), pero sin sumar los totales, es decir el `NoEconomico`. En total me estarían contando 34 registros, espero haberme explicado.

Mi resultado deseado sería así:

```
CeEmplazamiento   Total
Celaya              34
```

Comment: No entiendo del todo. ¿Puedes incluir el resultado deseado en foma tabular de acuerdo al ejemplo que incluistes, para que podamos verlo?

Comment: Y de paso, no tiene sentido usar el `DISTINCT` si ya tienes el `GROUP BY NoEconomico`.

Comment: Claro, estoy de acuerdo, sin embargo es una forma de hacerlo, Puede haber varios caminos, quizas la solución que alguno de ustedes pueda ser mas corta, concreta y lógica. :-)

Comment: TODAS LAS RESPUESTAS FUERON MUY BUENAS Y CON LÓGICA DIFERENTE, GRACIAS A TODOS. SALUDOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo del todo porqué necesitas devolver `CeEmplazamiento` en el resultado, ya que forma parte de uno de los filtros. A menos que el filtro se pueda ajustar de forma que varios valores para `CeEmplazamiento` son posibles.

En todo caso, esto lo harías con un `GROUP BY` en una subquery dentro de otro `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CeEmplazamiento, COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT CeEmplazamiento, NoEconomico
          FROM prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria
         WHERE RPMEventos <> 0
           AND AccountId = 9159
           AND FechaInicio BETWEEN '2016-11-27' AND '2016-12-31'
           AND CeEmplazamiento LIKE 'Celaya'
         GROUP BY CeEmplazamiento, NoEconomico) t
 GROUP BY CeEmplazamiento
```

Una mejor opción que se me ocurre es usar un `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)`. Esto simplifica la consulta considerablemente:

```
SELECT CeEmplazamiento, COUNT(DISTINCT NoEconomico)
  FROM prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria
 WHERE RPMEventos <> 0
   AND AccountId = 9159
   AND FechaInicio BETWEEN '2016-11-27' AND '2016-12-31'
   AND CeEmplazamiento LIKE 'Celaya'
 GROUP BY CeEmplazamiento
```

Comment: Uff Excelente, esta mas corta la respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si solo deseas contar las filas puedes utilizar un COUNT:

```
SELECT t.CeEmplazamiento , COUNT(1) FROM (select distinct CeEmplazamiento ,NoEconomico,
        count(NoEconomico) as Totales
        from  prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria  
        where RPMEventos <> 0 and AccountId = 9159  and FechaInicio between '2016-11-27' and '2016-12-31' and CeEmplazamiento like 'Celaya'
        group by CeEmplazamiento ,NoEconomico) t
        GROUP BY t.CeEmplazamiento
```

Comment: Correcto, pero que crees, me manda un error con un parentesis

Comment: Le agregué el ` t` al final. Siempre hay que asignarle una alias a una tabla derivada. A ver si eso funciona mejor.

Comment: Exacto, esa es la respuesta... Pero, ahora un favor: ¿Como agregar la columna como CeEmplazamiento.

Comment: Edite la respuesta con la columna que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente haciendo el `COUNT` de `NoEconomico`

```
SELECT
    CeEmplazamiento
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT NoEconomico) AS Total
FROM prm_FEMSA_IndicadoresTelemetria
WHERE RPMEventos <> 0
    AND AccountId = 9159
    AND FechaInicio BETWEEN '2016-11-27'
    AND '2016-12-31'
    AND CeEmplazamiento LIKE 'Celaya'
GROUP BY CeEmplazamiento
```

Comment: Ok, están correctos, pero, lo que me interesa es que cuente el total de este subquery, es decir si contamos el numero economico me daria 34 registros de este mismo subquery, sus consultas me arrojan el mismo resultado, que el que estoy agregando.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta. Asumiendo que tu columna se llama `CeEmplazamiento` solo la tienes que agregar a la agrupación, esto para mostrar el total de registros que coresponden a esa columna.

Comment: ¡¡¡Exacto!!!, ese es mi resultado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Extraño.. yo esperaría que esta consulta devuelve 34 registros como en la pregunta en vez de combinarlas en un registro. Tal vez hay algo que no entendí :)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @sstan se estarían mostrando los 34 registros. De hecho, desde mi punto de vista no veo la necesidad de realizar un *subquery*, me parecería que solo agrupando el `CeEmplazamiento` sería suficiente :) Edité mi respuesta, quitando el agruamiento del `NoEconomico`

Comment: Si solo agrupas con `CeEmplazamiento` entonces el resultado sería mayor a 34.  Porque 34 es la cantidad de valores `NoEconomico` ***distintos***, mientras que con una simple agrupación por `CeEmplazamiento`, estaría contando todos los registros sin tomar en cuenta los valores distintos. Pero ahora que lo pienso, si modificas tu consulta para que le agregues el `DISTINCT` dentro del `COUNT` ... `COUNT(DISTINCT NoEconomico)` ... entonces creo que allí sí funcionaría bien, y definitivamente me parecería una mejor opción que usar un subquery.

Comment: @sstan sin duda alguna, también lo veo perfecto de esa manera :D